# Datareader from LINQ Query for SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I'm using this library:

[Link to EntityDataReader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader)

to put some linq query results from a xml parse to a database with a sqlbulkcopy which us es a datareader to put the data directly without using datatables or such data structures.

I am not able to implement it.

This is the code I wrote so far without any success:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str_XmlToParse);

            //ORDINI

            IEnumerable<XDocument> xdod;

            var orders = from c in xdoc.Descendants("ordersdata").AsEnumerable().Descendants("order").AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             Client_ID = (string)c.Element("Client").Element("ID"),
                             Doc_ID = (string)c.Element("ord_ID"),
                             Doc_data = (DateTime)c.Element("ord_datetime"),
                         };
      IDataReader dr = orders.AsDataReader();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var newOrders =
                            from i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalToSend)
                            select new Order
                            {
                                customer_name = "Customer " + i % 100,
                                quantity = i % 9,
                                order_id = i,
                                order_entry_date = DateTime.Now
                            };

                    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con,
                      SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints |
                      SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                      SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, tran);

                    bc.BatchSize = 1000;
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "order_queue";
                    bc.WriteToServer(newOrders.AsDataReader());

                    tran.Commit();
                }
                con.Close();
```

which is mostly a copy of what is in the examples of that library.

I am not even understanding correctly what's going on with all their weird castings, but I need it to work. (believe me I tried to understand)

I keep getting this error:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable AnonymousType#1>' does
>   not contain a definition for 'AsDataReader' and no extension method
>   'AsDataReader' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable AnonymousType#1>' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is it? How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: PS. I assume this is a compiler error and not an exception. Correct?

Comment: Hi there. I'm desperate to get hold of this library. I followed the link but it's been retired. Anyone know where I can download it?

Comment: @serlingpa 
Maybe it's too late, but....

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-783fc64b/sourcecode?fileId=94546&pathId=1773531594

Comment: As of 2020, there was a version still available on GitHub: [Repository/Repository.EntityFramework/EntityDataReader.cs](https://github.com/matthewschrager/Repository/blob/master/Repository.EntityFramework/EntityDataReader.cs), maintained by Matthew Schrager after Microsoft retired it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically the error say that you cannot apply the method "AsDataReader" with parameter an "IEnumerable" object because there is not such a method with this definition. If it might help, try to add in the references the DLL "System.Data.Entity" and [System.Data.EntityClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.aspx)

Comment: Tried that, but I didn't expect it to work. It's just a problem of bad casting in from anonymous type to Ienumerable list or something.

Comment: what type is "orders" variable? becuase I guess that, the result of your LINQ query does not return something that you can apply "AsDataReader()" method. By the way: why have you put 2 ".AsEnumerable()" ? i guess you just need one

Comment: Just taken a look at the sample you added. You need `using Microsoft.Samples.EntityDataReader`at the top (unless you have changed to source to the `EntityDataReader.cs` file). The reason being is that you need to make the compiler look for the `Microsoft.Samples.EntityDataReader.EntityDataReaderExtensions` static class.

Comment: Also you need to actually included the `EntityDataReader.cs` file in your solution (but I hope that is a no brainer).

Comment: Actually I've already added that class in the project. But adding manually using Microsoft.Samples.EntityDataReader; in the top inclusions solved it. Thanks Aron. If you make it as answer I'll flag it as accepted answer.